Permission Denied Error When Cloning Cheatsheets with Cheat
I want to set up cheat on my Ubuntu system. When I run the command to initialize the config file and download the community cheatsheets, I encounter a permission denied error. Here is the process and the error message I receive:
$ cheat 
A config file was not found. Would you like to create one now? [Y/n]: Y 
Would you like to download the community cheatsheets? [Y/n]: Y
Cloning community cheatsheets to /home/m/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community.
failed to run installer: failed to clone cheatsheets: failed to clone cheatsheets: open /home/m/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community: permission denied

It seems like the issue is related to permissions in the directory where cheat is trying to clone the cheatsheets. How can I resolve this permission issue to successfully clone the community cheatsheets?
Additional Information:

I have already reinstalled cheat using: sudo snap remove cheat ; sudo snap install cheat
I have the following version installed: cheat 4.4.0.build.2 from Michael (bernermic)
I have not modified the permissions of the /home/m/.config directory.
Running cheat without downloading the cheatsheets works fine (e.g. cheat --help).

Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated; Thanks!
UPDATE
I also tried to reinstall using the --purge option as follows:
sudo snap remove --purge cheat ; sudo snap install cheat

Subsequently I created my own config file by running the command listed by cheat --help:
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/cheat && cheat --init > ~/.config/cheat/conf.yml

And the relevant files/dirs have the following permissions:
$ stat -c '%a %U %G' ~/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community
700 m m 
$ stat -c '%a %U %G' ~/.config/cheat/conf.yml
600 m m
# and my username is 'm'
$ whoami
m

The error I get right now is:
$ cheat man
failed to load config: could not read config file: open /home/m/.config/cheat/conf.yml: permission denied


If the file is already existing, then you're lacking a write permission to edit it, otherwise if the file doesn't exists it means you're lacking a write permission on the folder where the program is trying to copy the configuration, from the message it sounds like /home/m/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community would be the target directory (and not the destination file), so what are its permissions? stat -c '%a %U %G' /home/m/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community, and what's the real username?

Uninstalling without --purge probably didn't avail because without --purge normally packages will leave their configuration in place upon uninstallation

I wonder if this is due to the snap confinement model - in particular the personal-files interface ?

Thanks @kos for your feedback. I added the relevant information to the question.

The following steps solved it for me.
step 1: Install cheat directly
I installed the cheat command directly by using the instructions listed on github:
https://github.com/cheat/cheat/blob/master/INSTALLING.md.
If I used version 4.4.2 as listed on github, I got the following error:
$ cheat git
cheat: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by cheat)
cheat: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by cheat)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 so I tried a slightly older release (4.4.0), as follows:
cd /tmp   && wget https://github.com/cheat/cheat/releases/download/4.4.0/cheat-linux-amd64.gz   && gunzip cheat-linux-amd64.gz   && chmod +x cheat-linux-amd64   && sudo mv cheat-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/cheat

step 2: Make sure the relevant folders en conf.yaml exists
I created the relevant folders and the conf.yaml:
mkdir -p ~/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community
cheat --init > ~/.config/cheat/conf.yml

step 3: Download the cheat sheets
Then I installed the cheat sheets with the following command:
git clone https://github.com/cheat/cheatsheets ~/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community

step 4: Adjust the pager in conf.yaml
Then I got the following error:
$ cheat git
failed to write to pager: exec: "PAGER_PATH": executable file not found in $PATH

So, finally, I had to adjust the 'pager: PAGER_PATH' in ~/.config/cheat/yaml to:
pager: less -FRX

Then I finally had a working cheat:
$ cheat git                                                                                             
# To set your identity:
git config --global user.name <name>
git config --global user.email <email>                                               
...


You have installed a Snap package
Snap packages are great (if they are designed correctly), they have two positive aspect, first it is security they work in a confined place and only with the allowed security that is placed on them by the designer, for the second reason you may install or uninstall them with no effect on your computer. If a package has a dependency to another package, the minimal of that package will be installed also.
They have special rules The .config has to go where snap package has designed the place for it otherwise the package/program fails.
cheat
A config file was not found. Would you like to create one now? [Y/n]: y
Would you like to download the community cheatsheets? [Y/n]: y
Cloning community cheatsheets to /home/"my user name"/snap/cheat/common/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/community.
Enumerating objects: 335, done.
Counting objects: 100% (335/335), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (310/310), done.
Total 335 (delta 43), reused 213 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
Cloning personal cheatsheets to /home/"my user name"/snap/cheat/common/.config/cheat/cheatsheets/personal.
Created config file: /home/"my user name"/snap/cheat/common/.config/cheat/conf.yml
Please read this file for advanced configuration information.

Edit after the snap was removed, it also removed the folder/home/"my user name"/snap/cheat.
